# Need to take out count of various value in linux

Tags: shell-script, shell, text-processing

```
aff_id=752&off_id=4503trans_id=acacthf60cxr
aff_id=752&off_id=4553trans_id=acacthf60cxr
aff_id=752&off_id=4543trans_id=acacthf60cxr
aff_id=752&off_id=4543trans_id=acacthf60cxr
aff_id=752&off_id=4553trans_id=acacthf60cxr
aff_id=752&off_id=4503trans_id=acacthf60cxr
aff_id=752&off_id=4513trans_id=acacthf60cxr
aff_id=752&off_id=4513trans_id=acacthf60cxr
aff_id=752&off_id=4503trans_id=acacthf60cxr
```

this is the format of my file with same aff_id and different "off_id". I need to take out the count of based on "off_id".

Comment: can you please specify more about the needed output you want to reach? could you also provide a sample output of the above

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Awk** solution:

```
awk -F'[=&]' '{ a[substr($4,0,4)]++ }END{ for(i in a) print i,a[i] }' file
```

- `-F'[=&]'` - complex field separator
- `a[substr($4,0,4)]++` - `off_id` value is in 4th field `$4` and would have format like `4503trans_id`.
  Therefore, `substr($4,0,4)` will extract the needed value `4503`. 
   The array `a` will be indexed with `off_id` values having its occurrences as value

---

The output:

```
4503 3
4513 2
4543 2
4553 2
```

Comment: This is right. Could you please explain this command.

Comment: @RishabhBahukhandi, yes, see my explanation